# Unable to login to new TYPO3 10.4.8

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

New TYPO3 v10.4.8 installation on Azure Cloud. Setup:

- Ubuntu version 20.4
- PHP version 7.3
- Cloudflare DNS and SSL

Right after the installation process, when I log-in to the TYPO3 backend (https://mydomain.to/typo3), I get the following error message:

> **Oops, an error occurred!**
> Invalid referrer for `/main`

The log file shows the following entry:

```
Sun, 13 Sep 2020 10:03:48 +0000 [CRITICAL] request="025e24a027590"
component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception
handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1588095936: Invalid referrer for /main
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\Security\InvalidReferrerException thrown in file
/var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Security/
ReferrerEnforcer.php in line 104.
Requested URL: http://mydomain.to/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=
--AnonymizedToken--&referrer-refresh=1599991429 - {"TYPO3_MODE":"BE","exception":
"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\Security\\InvalidReferrerException: Invalid referrer for
/main in /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/Security/ReferrerEnforcer.php:104\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http/
RouteDispatcher.php(104): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\Security\\ReferrerEnforcer->
handle(Array)\n
#1 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http/RouteDispatcher.php(52): TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Http\\RouteDispatcher->enforceReferrer(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n
#2 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http/RequestHandler.php(94): TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Http\\RouteDispatcher->dispatch(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n
#3 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Middleware/SignalSlotDeprecator.php(49): TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Http\\RequestHandler->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n
#4 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Middleware\\SignalSlotDeprecator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Http\\RequestHandler))\n
#5 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/SiteResolver.php(69): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n
#6 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Middleware\\SiteResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n
#7 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/AdditionalResponseHeaders.php(41): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n
#8 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Middleware\\AdditionalResponseHeaders->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n
#9 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/OutputCompression.php(47): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n
#10 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Middleware\\OutputCompression->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n
#11 /var/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/BackendUserAuthenticator.php(78): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n
[...]
```

The request arrives as HTTP at the server. I'd expect HTTPS. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Which web server is running? Do you have a correct configuration, e.g. htaccess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that if Cloudflare does the SSL termination you might need to configure TYPO3 with reverse proxy settings. See `[SYS][reverseProxy*]` in the install tool. This [bug report](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91420) has more details.

Another thing you can check: with TYPO3 10.4.2 a Same-Origin Request Forgery protection was introduced. Some proxy servers might remove the HTTP Referer header which would make  it necessary to deactivate this protection mechanism. This can be done by setting `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['features']['security.backend.enforceReferrer'] = false` either using Install Tool's feature toggles or according deployment techniques. See the [Security Bulletin TYPO3-CORE-SA-2020-006](https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-core-sa-2020-006) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

- I had the root certificates installed on my origin server

To fix the issue for my TYPO3 installation (11LTS), I needed to make sure that "Full (strict)" was enabled in the CloudFlare control panel and *not* "flexible".